# Problems to reload TableView with tableView.reloadData()

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm relatively new to programming with swift and have a question that i just got stuck with.

I have a TableView Controller in which you can enter the names of films.
If you press the "Done" button, the new entered name should appear in the TableView and be saved with CoreData.
Saving also works wonderfully, but the problem is that the newly created name only appears in the list when the app is restarted.

Now I thought that the view would be reloaded with "tableView.reloadData ()".
Unfortunately, he will not.

This is how I created it:

My ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    static let filmCellIndentifier = "filmCell"
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.tableView.reloadData() // TODO: -> don´t reload Cell Data if "DoneButton" in "CreateFilmTableViewController" isn't pressed ???
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "Filmbook"
    }
    
    private func film(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Film {
        return CoreDataManager.shared.availableFilms()[indexPath.row]
    }
}


extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CoreDataManager.shared.numberOfFilms
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let filmCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ViewController.filmCellIndentifier, for: indexPath)
        let film = self.film(atIndexPath: indexPath)
        filmCell.textLabel?.text = film.title
        return filmCell
    }    
}
```

Here i create a new Film:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CreateFilmTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
  
    @IBAction func dismissButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
     
    @IBAction func createFilmButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let title = titleTextField.text != nil ? titleTextField.text! : ""
        let date = datePicker.date
        CoreDataManager.shared.createFilmbook(withTitle: title, date: date)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

And my CoreData Manager:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {

    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    

    var numberOfFilms: Int {
        return availableFilms().count
    }
 
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FilmbookT")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:  { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
 
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    func createFilmbook(withTitle title: String, date: Date) {
        let film = Film(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        film.title = title
        film.date = date
        try! persistentContainer.viewContext.save() // TODO -> Error Handling -> ("try!")
        
    }

    func availableFilms() -> [Film] {
        
        let filmFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Film>(entityName: "Film")
        filmFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
        
        let availableFilms = try! persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(filmFetchRequest) // TODO -> //Error Handling -> ("try!")
        
        return availableFilms
    }
}
```

Can you please help me find the bug?
Many Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you tried to `reloadData` when the `done` button is pressed?

Comment: Yes i tried, but it has no effect...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a local variable for the table view data source in the view controller, so you shouldn't have the *availableFilms()* and *numberOfFilms* in the CoreDataManager. The manager's responsibility should be only saving the newly added objects and returning the so far added ones.

I answered a similar question right now, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616364/14675707

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to listen the change of CoreData? After you create a new Film, the new object may not be inserted into Core Data yet so reloadData can not fetch the new one

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextObjectsDidChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextWillSave(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextWillSave, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextDidSave(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: nil)
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/core-data-notifications-with-swift-acc8232a674e

But, i agree with the solution of @marci0907